# Nested objects overwriting each other

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I'm having some issues with what would seem to me a fairly simple datastructure. I have an object called mylist with 1. an nested empty {} in it and 2. a function to add objects into (1). Please consider the following code:

```
var object1 = {name: "Object_1"}
var object2 = {name: "Object_2"}
var mylist = {
    list: {},
    add: function(item, val){
        this.list[item] = val
    }
}
mylist.add(object1,5)
mylist.add(object2,10)
console.log(mylist)
```

Now, I would expect the output to be

> { list: { object1: 5, object2: 10 }, add: [Function] }

But instead what I get is:

> { list: { '[object Object]': 10 }, add: [Function] }

For some reason, previous objects in the list are overwritten. Also there seems to be some sort of a conversion to string happening (because of the quotation marks), but I'm not sure why. Why am I not getting the output I expect? Does anyone has a good resource on this?

Thanks a lot in advance.
Maurits

Comment: `some sort of a conversion to string happening ` that's because of `toString()`.

Comment: If the answers fulfill you're need, please accept them so as to remove them from unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when you add a property to a object like `this.list[item]` JavaScript implicitly converts the property into String using `toString()`(JavaScript properties have keys a strings).

Now when running `toString()` on `object1` and `object2` the result is `[Object object]`. So when first object is added to `list` it's key becomes `[Object object]`. When second object is added, it will also have same key `[Object object]`, hence will overwrite the previous one.

So to make the your code working just add `.name` to `item`.

```
var object1 = {name: "Object_1"};
var object2 = {name: "Object_2"};
var mylist = {
    list: {},
    add: function(item, val){
        this.list[item.name] = val;
    }
}
mylist.add(object1,5);
mylist.add(object2,10);
console.log(mylist.list);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are passing an object not a string, so whenever you do this:

```
mylist.add(object1,5);
```

instead of passing the object `object1`, you should pass a string:

```
mylist.add(object1.name,5);
```

this will return:

```
{ list: { "Object_1": 5 }, add: [Function] }
```

otherwise if you do not send a string whatever you pass will be converted into a string